# Samba share across two subnets

Tags: windows, samba, smb, subnet

I am trying to access a samba share on CentOS7 from other PC in a different subnet.

- Samba version 4.4.4
- Server: CentOS7
- Clients: Windows 10, Ubuntu Mate, Windows 7.
- Subnet A: 11.22.66.64/26 (old)
- Subnet B: 11.22.33.0/25 (new)

The server is in subnet A (this will change in the future because we will leave subnet A). Access from all PCs in subnet A works fine.

All PCs in subnet B don't work, which means they do not have access to the share. Also I cannot see the share in the Networks Browser from Windows or Mate.

I can ping in both directions, I can access e.g. an Apache server in subnet A from PCs in subnet B. The pc with the share also runs the dhcpd. The PC in subnet B get the right IP-addresses from it.

The subnets are in the same physical network, connected to one router, which is the gateway to the outside (university network, Internet). I do not have direct access to it's configuration (we are part of an university network).

The smb.conf:

```
[global]

workgroup = xyz
interfaces = lo enp3s0 11.22.33.0/25 11.22.66.64/26
bind interfaces only = yes
hosts allow = 127. 11.22.33. 11.22.66.

security = user
passdb backend = tdbsam

map to guest = Bad User
guest account = nobody

local master = yes
os level = 255
preferred master = yes

domain master = yes

wins support = yes

# Share Definitions
[home]
...
```

What can I do?

## Solution

The problem was with the firewall of our router/gateway which blocked the ports used by SMB (135 - 139 and 445). After our IT department opened the ports it worked.

Comment: I *think* you need to setup the devices in subnet B to use the Samba server, as a WINS server. You can do this by assigning the value via DHCP, or manually.

I'm leaving this as a comment as I'm not 100% sure and can't test currently.

Comment: @djsmiley2k I tried this, but it doesn't help. But I think I found the problem: The router firewall may block the ports used by SMB (135 - 139 and 445). I will give an update when IT opened the ports. Thanks

Comment: The firewall was the problem.

Answer (score -3):

```
remote announce=192.168.11.255/WORKGROUP 192.168.51.255 192.168.255.255/WORKGROUP
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained in detail what setting `remote announce` to your suggest value does exactly.  I am not asking for myself, I already know what it does, so you should edit your answer and improve it.  If you don't wish to improve your answer just ignore this comment.